# Cakephp 3 process code after page response

Tags: cakephp, apache2, cakephp-3.0, php-7

One of the requirements of the project I am working on is that I log the connections made to the site, due to the amount of processing being done to get as much information as possible I would like to process this after the page has been sent back to the user.

At the moment I am running my code in the `afterFilter` of my appController:

```
public function afterFilter(Event $event){
    $log_request = new  RequestsController;
    $log_request->log_request();    
}
```

I am attempting to run this in `afterRender` of my appController:

```
public function afterRender(Event $event, $viewFile){
   $log_request = new  RequestsController;
   $log_request->log_request();    
}
```

But I can not seem to get the code to execute or if it does then I do not know how to find out what the error being thrown is.

If somebody can point me towards an example of this being done or a concurrent method of doing this (it needs to be logged within a second of the request) I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$log_request = new  RequestsController;` you don't instantiate controllers inside controllers. You want to learn [the MVC design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) first when using a MVC based framework or you'll end up with a non maintainable piece of horrible spaghetti code. I recommend you to do the blog tutorial to get a basic understanding.

> If somebody can point me towards an example of this being done or a concurrent method of doing this (it needs to be logged within a second of the request) I would appreciate it.

Read this chapter: [CakePHP Logging](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html) Taken from there:

> Logging data in CakePHP is easy - the log() function is provided by the LogTrait, which is the common ancestor for many CakePHP classes. If the context is a CakePHP class (Controller, Component, View,...), you can log your data. You can also use Log::write() directly.

Add the log trait to the AppController, pass the request to the log() method and configure the logging to log these requests to whatever you prefer either in `afterRender()` or if you want to do it really late, do it in `__destruct()`.

Comment: I should have explained this more! this data is being logged to a database, and needs to execute on every request, as the appController is where i set the authentication I decided to put this code just under it. The data can be viewed from the controller actions. I do agree that this does not belong here but I don't know where to place it otherwise. Following your link about logging should I have a controller for viewing this data and use the logging functions to write this to the database? if so how do I do this after the page has been sent to the client?

Comment: This won't change my answer. Just log to the database table via a DB log engine. I don't know if the CakePHP core has changed but you can try this one, https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-database-log it's the implementation of the DB log engine from the documentation. Just read the whole logging chapter. Also, logging to a SQL DB like this isn't a good idea performancewise if you get a lot requests. Why is the web server log not sufficient?

Comment: Thank you for this :) My only outstanding question now is how do I do this after the response has been sent to the client? I have read that PHP does not support multi-threading and the client should not have to wait for this processing before getting the page. (it takes about 0.6ms according to the cake debug toolkit). The reason for a database is because the project is intended to react based on certain conditions from a history of this information.

Comment: You need to step through this and figure out when __destruct() *exactly* is called. But I'm pretty sure the request has already been sent at this point and just cleanup and garbage collection is running php internal. Again: Check the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php Also the fact it was sent doesn't mean the client received it. :) Depending on how strict the requirement is I would not rely on that and try to find another solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)